# puppet hiera is not resolving variables from hierarchy

Tags: puppet, hierarchy, hiera

I have defined in hiera.yaml something like this:

```
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::fqdn}"
  - "%{fqdn}"
  - global
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppet/hieradata"
```

(I dont know which one is correct, so that's why I have both...)

but when I run `hiera -c ../hiera.yaml allowUsers --debug`

this is the output

```
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:07:02 +0200: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:07:02 +0200: Looking up allowUsers in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:07:02 +0200: Looking for data source global
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:07:02 +0200: Found allowUsers in global
["vagrant", "root"]
```

All is in this same directory

```
[root@localhost hieradata]# ll
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 28 Apr  7 20:14 centos-puppet.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 45 Apr  7 20:39 facts.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 83 Apr  7 20:42 global.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 28 Apr  7 20:15 production.yaml
```

also

```
[root@localhost hieradata]# facter fqdn
centos-puppet
```

So even in hierarchy fqdn name is higher, it looks like hiera is not even trying to resolv fqdn variables. I have no idea why.

```
[root@localhost hieradata]# puppet -V
3.8.6

[root@localhost hieradata]# hiera -v
1.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `hiera` on the command line, you need to manually specify any facts you want it to recognize.  There are several options for that, but for one-offs, the easiest is to specify them directly in the command:

```
hiera allowUsers -c ../hiera.yaml --debug fqdn=centos-puppet
```

When facts are passed in this way the fact name must match any interpolation tokens exactly in order to be recognized.  Thus, the above form should trigger make the `"%{fqdn}"` hierarchy level being recognized.  If you instead specified `::fqdn=centos-puppet` then it would make the `"%{::fqdn}"` level be recognized.  Note, however, that these two are not so distinct when Hiera is invoked by Puppet -- in that case, `%{fqdn}` resolves `fqdn` against the current scope, with very likely (but not necessarily) the same result as `"%{::fqdn}"`.

All this is covered in much greater detail in the [Hiera documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/1/command_line.html), which seems to have gotten a significant and long-overdue update recently.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explanation! Unfortunately it still does not work...

`[root@localhost hieradata]# hiera -c ../hiera.yaml --debug fqdn=centos-puppet allowUsers
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:34:10 +0200: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:34:10 +0200: Looking up fqdn=centos-puppet in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2016-04-07 22:34:10 +0200: Looking for data source global
allowUsers`

`[root@localhost hieradata]# cat centos-puppet.yaml
---
allowUsers:
  - "proxy"
`

Comment: @syncerror, my apologies, I forgot that Hiera is sensitive to the order of non-option arguments (as is also described in the docs).  The first non-option argument is always interpreted as the key to look up, and your output shows exactly that effect.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! You helped me a lot!